# How to parse argument with argparse which contains other arguments

Tags: python, bash, argparse

I am writing a script, using argparse, which is supposed to take user input. The final argument was to be --args, and with that argument, I wanted to accept a string of arguments, which will then be passed to a bash script which is called within my script.

Here is a really simplified version:

In Python (myscript.py):

```
import argparse
import subprocess


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--name", type=str, help=description, default="")
parser.add_argument("--args", type=str, nargs='+', help=description, default="")

args = parser.parse_args()
subprocess.call("myotherscript.sh {}".format(args.script, args.args))
```

In Bash:

```
python myscript.py --name myname --args --arguments for --the inner --script here
```

So far I've tried escaping the `--`s in Bash (e.g. `\\--the inner` etc) which works and I can replace them back in Python (`" ".join([s.replace("\\", "") for s in args.args])`), but that isn't very elegant.

I was wondering if there was a better way to handle this with argparse.

Comment: But you are probably looking for [`ArgumentParser.parse_known_args`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing).

Comment: @Graipher yeah sorry typo, will add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argparse` has the possibility to [only partially parse arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing). This works as long as there is no overlap between the arguments for this script and the ones to be passed along*.

```
import argparse
import subprocess


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--name", help=description, default="")    # default type is already str

args, other_args = parser.parse_known_args()
subprocess.call("myotherscript.sh {}".format(" ".join(other_args)))
```

You can also avoid the `join`ing by using `list` addition:

```
subprocess.call(["myotherscript.sh"] + other_args))
```

---

*As mentioned in the documentation:

> **Warning**
>
> [Prefix matching](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#prefix-matching) rules apply to `parse_known_args()`. The parser may
>   consume an option even if it’s just a prefix of one of its known
>   options, instead of leaving it in the remaining arguments list.

Comment: Double dash `'--'` and `nargs=argparser.REMAINDER` can help get around the prefix matching problem.